# Accessing the data or dataItem used to bind a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataitem

I have a gridview for which I programmatically set the datasource and databind it to a collection of objects. For each row that is created I then use different methods in the  fields to extract the relevant information from the object like this one:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aliases">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# ( (MyItem)Container.DataItem).Aliases.ToString() %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My problem is that in the `OnRowDeleting` method I would preferably like to be able to access that `DataItem` using e g `MyGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItem` or in other way. But I can’t find how to configure the `Gridview` to retain the `DataItem`. **Is it possible to access the `DataItem` used and how would I configure it to do it?** If that’s not possible can I access the values that are bind by the methods? Or do I have to go with plan B and rewrite the datasource object collection to a datatable and then use datakeysnames?

Comment: Why can't you access it using var dataItem = MyGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItem; that will work.

Comment: I've tried to use that, but I get null.

Comment: whats the MyItem collection? type and fields?

Comment: @Teletha, what about var row = MyGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex]; Then you should have a list of cells. And you can extract the cells from the row.

Comment: @Jethro It's null to. Maybe this is a postback problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItem` should generally work but I guess that you are probably relying the view-state for retaining grid data on post-backs. In such case, you will get the `DataItem` property as NULL.

Work-around can be to always re-bind the grid with actual data in each postback early in page life cycle (say `page_load`).

However, in your case, you can very well use `DataKeyNames`. Contrary to your belief, you don't need a DataTable for this property to work. For example, if your class has property named `ItemId` indicating the key for your object then you can use `DataKeyNames="ItemId"` in the markup and refer it in `OnRowDeleting` using [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeleteeventargs.keys.aspx) property of event arguments.

Comment: ViewState isn't used, however other things are saved in Session state. To use the DataKeyNames the propertys must be serializable correct?

Comment: @teletha, actual data key values are stored in control-state (or view-state) so yes-your key property type has to be `serializable`. But most often, your key properties will be combination of int, string, guid and those are already marked as serializable.

Comment: I see! These key values, are they the propertys of the DataItem that is being bound or how do I set/get these? Can I e g give a name to a row in the ItemTemplete?

Comment: @Teletha, assuming you are binding your grid with the collection of objects of type 'MyItem' and if this class has a property called 'ItemId' then you have to set `DataKeyNames="ItemId"` at gridview level then `Keys` property of `GridViewDeleteEventArgs` will have value of this property for the object bound to the row being deleted.

Comment: From what I can tell `DataKeyNames` won't work for the same reason as `DataItem` - it is only available when the grid is `DataBound` during the life cycle, which is not on postback.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

"The DataItem property is only available during and after the RowDataBound event of a GridView control."

Therefore, access the DataItem in the RowDataBound event:

Lets say you bind a List(Of Vehicle) to the grid:

```
Dim vehicles As List(Of Vehicle) = Vehicle.GetAll()
gvVehicles.DataSource = vehicles
gvVehicles.DataBind()
```

In the RowDataBound event access the DataItem:

```
Protected Sub gvVehicles_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
       Dim veh As Vehicle = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, Vehicle)
       If Not veh Is Nothing Then
            Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(e.Row.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox)
                chkBox.Checked = True
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is hardly helpful when trying to process `OnRowDeleting`.

Comment: Also probably didn't help the OP much as it's VB, not C#....

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is very dated question at this point - however, I've just run into a similar issue and none of these answers resolved the issue; so I figured I'd post an alternative solution. In my scenario, the issue was on the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event. So, it should theoretically hold true for `OnRowDeleting` but not necessarily on `OnRowDeleted` (depending on where exactly in the process the row is deleted).

My solution was to simply add a `HiddenField` for the data that I didn't want to be visible in the `GridView`, for example:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvTutorGroups" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sqlTutorGroups" DataKeyNames="TTGP_Group_Code" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8" EmptyDataText="You have no tutor groups to display." Style="margin: 0 auto; width: 870px;" OnRowDataBound="gvTutorGroups_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfTTGPISN" Value="<%# Eval("TTGP_ISN") %>" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TTGP_Group_Code" HeaderText="TG Code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PRPH_Title" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TTGP_Start_Date" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TTGP_End_Date" HeaderText="End Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Then I just used the `FindControl` method to access that field, like so:

```
protected void gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvTutorGroups.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowIndex == gvTutorGroups.SelectedIndex)
        {
            row.CssClass = "rowSelected";

            DataRowView dataItem = (DataRowView)row.DataItem;
            HiddenField hfTGIsn = (HiddenField)this.Parent.FindControl("hfTGisn");
            hfTGIsn.Value = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfTTGPISN")).Value;
        }
        else
        {
            row.CssClass = "";
        }
    }
}
```

It's not an ideal solution, but it works.